# VBA Excel - Powerpoint export

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I've the following piece of code which exports excel sheets to powerpoint. In each sheet it takes the range from cells A1 and A2 and copies that range into powerpoint.

Now I want to add two functions, but I have no clue how to do this, so I am hoping anyone can help me with this?

1 - In sheets where only a table is included, the code does exactly what it's supposed to do. However in some sheets I've included a picture or a chart and these are not properly pasted in excel. (only a blank picture is copied in the powerpoint slide). Now I want to make a code that uses my input from cell "C1" to determine whether this slide needs to be pasted as an image or as a normal paste. I've tried to fix this but my code continuously gets an error. Is there any way that I can adjust this code so that I will get it working?

2 - The code now copies all worksheets, but I want it to start at sheet 7 and continue from there till the end. Thus skipping the first 6 worksheets. Does anyone have a clue how I can exclude these sheets in my VBA?

```
Sub PrintPPT()
 'Step 1:  Declare variables
      Dim pp As Object
      Dim PPPres As Object
      Dim PPSlide As Object
      Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
      Dim MyRange As String

'Step 2:  Open PowerPoint, add a new presentation and make visible
      Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
      Set PPPres = pp.Presentations.Add
      pp.Visible = True

'Step 3:  Start the loop through each worksheet
      For Each xlwksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      MyRange = xlwksht.Range("A1").Value & ":" & xlwksht.Range("A2").Value
      xlwksht.Range(MyRange).Copy

'Step 4:  Count slides and add new blank slide as next available slide number
'(the number 12 represents the enumeration for a Blank Slide)
      SlideCount = PPPres.Slides.Count
      Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount + 1, 12)
      PPSlide.Select

'Step 5:  Paste the picture and adjust its position
      PPPres.ApplyTemplate ("C:\Users\Template.potx")

      Pastetype = xlwksht.Range("C1").Value

    ' Pastetype will be "PasteSpecial DataType:=2" for images
    ' Pastetype will be "Paste.Select" for normal

    PPSlide.Shapes.pastetype  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile          


         'pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
          pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 85
          pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 7.2
         'pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 600

'Step 6:  Add the title to the slide then move to next worksheet
      Next xlwksht

'Step 7:  Memory Cleanup
      pp.Activate
      Set PPSlide = Nothing
      Set PPPres = Nothing
      Set pp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Erik, is copy-paste linked an option for you? If yes, no need to have special code. As soon as you update your workbook, when opening the PowerPoint it will ask if you want to refresh the linked items. Accept it and VOILA.

Comment: Hi FDavidov, that's not really an option because the presentation is going to be sent out to various parties which don't have access to the linked excel file

Comment: Meaning that what you are sending would not get updated if you change the Excel (since they don't have it), right?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding it.. But although the charts won't be updated, I still wont see the charts in the powerpoint if I paste it as a link right? And every user who opens the powerpoint file will get an error that there are linkages which need to be updated. That is not something I prefer, as it will go to higher management (and I thus need a small clean powerpoint presentation..)

Comment: You may as well send a PDF instead. Can you? In any case, they will NOT get an error message but only a question if update links or not. If they say "NO", the presentation will be there. An alternative, you can send them a file in PowerPoint Show format (when they open it, it immediately starts a presentation without the need to start it after opening). If this is still not helpful, I'm afraid I ran out of ideas. Good luck!